# What is the meaning of `Forward compatible` code?

Tags: terminology

Backward compatibility means (as I understand it) that newer versions of the code will:

- Still be able to read data written by older versions
- Still be able to operate with older versions using some network protocol
- Basically, nothing will break when I upgrade a system to a newer version, even if it is just one part of a larger system, or uses resources created by the older system

But what is "Forward Compaitible"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility

Comment: Quick google search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility

Answer (score 4):

##### Backward compatibility vs forward compatibility

We have two versions of a software: the version **A**, and a newer version **B**. We say:

- **B** is backward compatible with **A** if everything that works on **A** will still work on **B**.
- **A** is forward compatible with **B** if everything that works on **A** will still work on **B**.
- **B** is backward compatible if it is backward compatible with all the versions < **B**.
- **A** is forward compatible if it is forward compatible with all the versions > **A**.

Answer (score 2):

Forward compatible bascially means that the code will be compatible with newer versions of the software. In other words, code you enter now will smoothly transition to the next software version. You could also think of it that the next version(s) of software will be reverse compatible with the current version.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility